# Draw a plus (+) sign using CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am not good with CALayer but I need to draw a plus (+) sign and I don't want to use an image as I want to animate the drawing. Any help?

Comment: Create two `CAShapeLayer`s forming a plus sign, where is the problem? If you make the situation more difficult on purpose you might want to find of solution on your own first.

Comment: why dont u draw two bezier paths one as horiozontal line and one as vertical line ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all the down votes, I was able to do it myself. Here's how for others who might need this

```
CGFloat height = 2.f;
CGFloat width = 3.f;
CGFloat cornerRadius =  1.f;

CALayer *hLayer = [CALayer layer];//this is the left - right stroke 
hLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)-(height/2), width, height);
hLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;

CALayer *vLayer = [CALayer layer];// this is the top - bottom stroke
vLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - (height/2), -3,height, width);
vLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;

[self.layer addSublayer:hLayer];
[self.layer addSublayer:vLayer];
```

Answer (score 2):

As luk2302 says, use a `CAShapeLayer`.

You can install a `CGPath` into a `CAShapeLayer`. You can get a `CGPath` from any `UIBezierPath`. (It has a `CGPath` property that lets you get to the underlying CGPath object for any `UIBezierPath`.)

I suggest reading up on UIBezierPath. It has methods `moveToPoint` and `addLineToPoint`.

You'd move to the top of your plus, add a line down, then move to the left of your plus and add a line across.

Note that you can also animate images, depending on the type of animation you are after. What kind of animation do you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way would be to use two UIView with the same background color and add them as a subview to another UIView. Then you can use the UIView animateWithDuration:... method to do your simple animations.